# What is Jabber, and how is it related to Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, xmpp

What else uses Jabber besides Facebook chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jabber** is the original name for **Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP)**  an open-standard communications protocol for message-oriented middleware based on **XML**

Unlike most instant messaging protocols, **XMPP** uses an open systems approach of development and application, by which anyone may implement an XMPP service and interoperate with other organizations' implementations.

[Some of the clients implementing Jabber](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/).

Comment: Which chat services use this?

Comment: I cannot positively confirm it but i believe   gTalk , AIM , Yahoo Messenger, ICQ and Windows Live are all already using it or shifting to it .

Comment: incorrect. gTalk uses it, and can interface with AIM, but AIM does not use it. Yahoo Messenger, MSN/Windows Live, and ICQ are all their own protocols, and do not currently and likely will not support XMPP.